# Join two tables mysqli

Tags: sql

I have a question about my select from two tables. I have this tables:

```
         pubstats                                sites

 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,                   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,                          
  `website_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,         `url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float(10,4) NOT NULL,          `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `impressions` varchar(30) NOT NULL,     `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL                    `date` date NOT NULL,
                                          `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending'
```

I want to select all dates from sites and impressions and amount from pubstats and display it! I tried with another select in loop but not work and i want to use JOIN function!

Now i have this select that display dates from sites table and i want for each website to display impressions and amount:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, url, name, category, date, status FROM sites WHERE username = '$username' order by id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $url, $name, $category, $date, $status);
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Then use a join function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.*, b.impression, b.amount
FROM sites a
INNER JOIN pubstats b
ON a.id = b.website_id
```

With this query you will select all columns from table sites (alias table a) and only two columns from table pubstats (alias table b)